# Heroku 500 internal server error, works on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have executed the command `heroku run rake db:migrate` many times at this point, that is not the issue I am having.

My application works perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy to Heroku, my /guestbooks page receives a 500 error from the Heroku logs.

I ran rake db:reset and then deleted my test db records thinking that my database might need to be clean going from test to production, but that did not work. I then ran heroku run rake db:migrate again to no avail. The app still works on localhost

Below are my MVC and routes. I wanted to see if anyone picks up on anything that could be causing the problem. I am stuck...

Controller

```
class GuestbooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_page

    def index
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new
    end

    def create
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new(guestbook_params)

        if @guestbook.save
            flash.now[:notice] = "Thanks for taking the time to write us! We greatly appreciate it!"
            render :new
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = "Your message failed to post, please try again"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def load_page
        @guestbooks = Guestbook.page(params[:page])
    end

    def guestbook_params
        params.require(:guestbook).permit(:name, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

Model

```
class Guestbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    paginates_per 5
end
```

View

```
<div class="paginate">
    <%=paginate @guestbooks%>
</div>

<div class="span1">
    <% @guestbooks.each do |g| %>
        <br/>
        <h4><%= g.name %>, <%= g.created_at %><br/></h4>
        <%= g.message %><br/>
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for @guestbook, url: guestbooks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="span2"><%= f.input :name %></div>
    <div class="span2"><%= f.input :email %></div>
    <div class="span3"><%= f.input :message %></div>
    <div class="span4"><%= f.button :submit %></div><br/><br/><br/>
<% end %>
```

`resources :guestbooks, only: [:create, :index]`

Logs

```
Dec 07 11:51:16 allbugsaside heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/guestbooks" host=allbugsaside.herokuapp.com request_id=c09830f2-e460-4700-9907-43a97391001f fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=1754 
Dec 07 11:51:17 allbugsaside heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=allbugsaside.herokuapp.com request_id=8c9a1f54-ea28-4d82-bc33-9e8dd3b1d56f fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
```

Comment: you should look at the logs to see what the cause of the 500 is. until you do that, it'd be just GUESSING at what the problem is.

Comment: What he said ^^ my favorite way to do this is to add on a free instance of Papertrail to my app. That way, everything is laid out super cleanly for you in realtime.

Comment: heroku logs would help you

Comment: I've looked at the logs a few times which is how I know its a 500 internal server error, but it's not showing me much. I originally just ran Heroku logs, but then installed Papertrail as per @CollinGraves, but it shows the same output. I posted the logs

Comment: Do you have [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) installed? Some logs may be missing if they go to a file or somewhere other than `STDOUT`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMcKnight. I installed it and got this error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "guestbooks" does not exist 

I tried deleting my guestbooks table and recreating it, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your `db/seed.rb` and `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: also, your index action does not define `@guestbooks`. Maybe add `@guestbooks = Guestbook.all` ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?